# Creating instance of a class registered in SysWOW64

Tags: dll, vb6, windows-server-2008

I have migrated my website from Windows Server 32 bit to Windows Server 2008R2 64 bit. The website has a VB6 dll that is being used for all the funcitons.

I have registered the 32bit dll by placing it in SysWOW64 folder. Also, I am able to see the classed registerd using regedit.exe in SysWOW64 folder.

But, when I tried creating instance in VB "Server.CreateObject('myclass')", I am getting error
"Error:429 ActiveX Component Cant create object"

The same works in the existing 32bit server.

Am I missing anything here. Or should I use a different line on creating instance for the class I registerd. Please let me know.

Comment: Turn it into an exe. From WSDK. On 64-bit Windows, a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit dynamic-link library (DLL). Additionally, a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL. However, 64-bit Windows supports remote procedure calls (RPC) between 64-bit and 32-bit processes (both on the same computer and across computers). On 64-bit Windows, an out-of-process 32-bit COM server can communicate with a 64-bit client, and an out-of-process 64-bit COM server can communicate with a 32-bit client.

Comment: Therefore, if you have a 32-bit DLL that is not COM-aware, you can wrap it in an out-of-process COM server and use COM to marshal calls to and from a 64-bit process.

Comment: Classic ASP? Make sure the AppPool has "Enable 32-bit Applications" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

finally did it.. needed to install vb 6 runtime, copy ishims.dll from Program files-> Internet Explorer to syswow 64 ( weird my dll had dependency on that) and lastbut not the least change Data Execution Prevention settings...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your website in 32 bit mode in IIS 7.5 manager.